# Cкрипт копирует испорченные файлы из всех подпапок в главную папку, вместо того, чтобы портить файлы в самих этих папках. - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача - Есть папка firefox. В ней есть множество других папок с файлами. Находясь в самой главной папке запускаю:

```
def corruptit(filE):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    os.system("echo '' > " + filE)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    os.rename(filE, filE + ".cpt")

def corrupter():
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("."):
        print("root", root)
        print("subdirs", subdirs)
        print("files", files)
        print("-"*10)
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                pass
            else:
                corruptit(filename)
```

Проблема в том, что когда запускаешь скрипт в главной папке, то скрипт копирует испорченные файлы из всех подпапок в главную папку, вместо того, чтобы портить файлы в самих этих папках. В чём моя ошибка ?

Comment: проблема в том что в функцию corruptit вы передаете имя файла, а не путь к нему. Передавайте в corruptit `os.path.join(root, filename)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в `corruptit(filename)` вы передаете имя файла без пути. Вот он и пишет в ту папку, откуда запускается.

Передавать надо полное имя файла, включая  `root`, `subdirs` и `filename`.